How do you apply only part of an Excel cell function to another cell?
I have an Excel sheet used to calculate the amount of money users of a store owe. Each item in the store has a cell that contains the price of that item. The Excel sheet appears something like this:
     a         b        c         d 
1 | Name | Lollipop | Apple |
2 |------|----------|-------| --------
3 | Bob  |    1     |   0   | ________
4 | Jim  |    0     |   1   |

Elsewhere in the table, we'll say in cell F7 and F8 just to keep it totally separate, are the prices for the lollipop and apple.
In column D I would like to put the total amount each person owes. For Bob that would look something like this: =((B3 * F7)+(C3 * F8))
If I were to drag D3 down to D4 to apply the same function the following would happen: =((B4 * F8)+(C4 * F9))
I want it to be B4 and C4, but do not want the F7 and F8 to change since the price stays in the same place. How would I do make it that F7 and F8 do not change?

Using a dollar sign in front of the cell reference values makes them absolute. So use $F$7 and $F$8 in your formula.

Here is the MS documentation if you want to read up on cell references

1. Using Absolute Ref with XLOOKUP
You could use absolute references as Ken White and cybernetic.nomad suggested to fix the price cells.
Here's one way to do it with looking up the prices based on item name, with name in $E$7:$E$8 and prices in F :
=SUMPRODUCT(B2:C2,XLOOKUP($B$1:$C$1,$E$7:$E$8,$F$7:$F$8))

Enter the above in D2 and fill down.

2. Named ranges
It is better to name the ranges: Define and use names in formulas - Microsoft Support
For example:



Name
Refers to:




items
=Sheet2!$E$7:$E$14


prices
=Sheet2!$F$7:$F$14


purchased_items
=Sheet2!$B$1:$C$1


quantities_per_customer
=Sheet2!$B2:$C2



When defining quantities_per_customer, first select the cells containing the quantities for a single customer, open Name Manager and adjust the reference fixed column ($B) and relative row (2), to change the row number when filling down.
With names defined, enter the following in D2 and fill down:
=SUMPRODUCT(quantities_per_customer,XLOOKUP(purchased_items,items,prices))


Best option may be is to use tables: Overview of Excel tables - Microsoft Support
